# Data in msqldump file are missing

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ubuntu-16.04

Few days ago I have reinstalled my system and installed mariadb as default mysql server. And now i have noticed a problem - whenever I try to create a dump of any database - it is created without data. Inside of dump file most of tables does not have insert query with data and dump file is very small (below 1mb).

I have tried to create dump files in a few ways:

1. Phpmyadmin export
2. Command line mysqldump -u user -p databesaname > dumpfile.name

But result is the same. So is there a way to fix this without reinstalling mysql server? I dont want to lose all my databases.

Specifications:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server Type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.0.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - Ubuntu 16.04

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Databesa client version : libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: b5c5906d452ec590732a93b051f3827e02749b83 $
PHP version: 7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
```

Comment: Maybe you have something in `my.cnf` that's overriding the default options for `mysqldump`

Comment: I didn't change anythink is default files of mariadb of mysql

Comment: Something must have changed or you wouldn't be getting different results. Anyway, if you want help more efficiently, ask the moderators to migrate this to [dba.se]